# Manual reinstall of ubuntu 16.04 on dual boot Windows 10 system does not proceed after hitting Install Now --> Continue

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10, livedvd

Due to a failure during upgrade to Kubuntu 16.04 from 15.10, on my dual-boot Windows 10/Kubuntu Dell Vostro 3450, I have been trying to upgrade to Ubuntu from Live DVD manually, using the "Something else" option, but it keeps failing, without displaying an error, after "Install Now". There is a warning popup displayed regarding partition misalignment:

> The partition /dev/sda5 assigned to / starts at an offset of 3072 bytes from the minimum alignment for this disk, which may lead to very poor performance.

but based on what I have read elsewhere, I should be able to proceed anyway.  However, when I click on the Continue button to proceed, it doesn't seem to 
do anything, and takes me back to the partitioning window.

Internet connection is disconnected and the "Download updates while installing" and "Install third-party software" options are also unticked, which was identified as a possible cause elsewhere, but no joy.

Any idea how to get beyond this step?  Help would be much appreciated, as I have now lost access to my Windows OS as well, due to restart taking me to the grub rescue menu (I may have written changes to disk during an earlier manual install attempt), which I have been unable to repair.

**Additional information:**
Before I attempted to reinstall, the original partition table was like this:

```
/dev/sda1    fat16                   101.94 Mib  357.00 Kib   101.60 Kib   diag
unallocated  unallocated             2.02 Mib    --           -- 
/dev/sda2    ntfs          RECOVERY  19.53 Gib   8.81 Gib     10.73 Gib    boot
/dev/sda3    ntfs          OS        379.00 Gib  120.89 Gib   258.12 Gib 
unallocated  unallocated             2.48 Mib    --           -- 
/dev/sda4    extended                300.00 Gib  --           --  
/dev/sda5    ext4          root      32.01 Gib   14.52 Gib    17.48 Gib 
/dev/sda6    linux-swap              16.00 Gib   0.00 Gib     16.00 Gib 
/dev/sda7    ntfs          share     32.01 Gib   133.43 Mib   31.87 Gib 
/dev/sda8    ext4          home      219.98 Gib  17.10 Gib    202.89 Gib 
unallocated  unallocated             2.49 Mib    --           --
```

After my first attempt at a reinstall, when the sda5 changes had been written to disk (which presumably is the reason why grub goes to the rescue prompt) the partition table is now:

```
/dev/sda1    fat16                   101.94 Mib  357.00 Kib   101.60 Kib   diag
unallocated  unallocated             2.02 Mib    --           -- 
/dev/sda2    ntfs          RECOVERY  19.53 Gib   8.81 Gib     10.73 Gib    boot
/dev/sda3    ntfs          OS        379.00 Gib  120.89 Gib   258.12 Gib 
unallocated  unallocated             2.48 Mib    --           -- 
/dev/sda4    extended                300.00 Gib  --           --  
/dev/sda5    ext4                    32.01 Gib   691.08 Mib   31.33 Gib 
/dev/sda6    linux-swap              16.00 Gib   0.00 Gib     16.00 Gib 
/dev/sda7    ntfs          share     32.01 Gib   133.43 Mib   31.87 Gib 
/dev/sda8    ext4          home      219.98 Gib  17.10 Gib    202.89 Gib 
unallocated  unallocated             2.49 Mib    --           --
```

Comment: Have you selected the old `/` , `swap` and `ESP` (EFI partition)? Do not tick format. The options to download updates  and/or install third-party software have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Did you select mount point of your installation partition? Also try formatting the installation partition to ext(4).

Comment: Thank you for your response @CelticWarrior.

I am not sure about the ESP partition, I don't recall having to do anything for that when I first set up my (working) dual-boot system.  The other Linux partitions, /  swap and home I did select. Out of these, I ticked format for / only.

Comment: @Moazzem, thanks, if by installation partition you mean the root partition then yes I did set the mount point, as / (and also formatted it, which is why, presumably, grub is going to the grub rescue prompt now)

Comment: You didn't before, the installer did it for you. But now, if you want to salvage as much as possible of the old installation, you'll have to use "Something else", select but not format all the aforementioned partitions (and mount points), and use the exact same user and password as before. If you already formated it in that failed attempt then there's no point in even keeping it, all your previous data is gone. Better to delete all Ubuntu partitions leaving unallocated space and then user the automatic "Install alongside option".

Comment: If your Windows 10 was installed in UEFI mode all you need to do is make the Windows Boot Manager entry first boot priority at UEFI settings, if you need to boot it meanwhile. If not, just do what I commented above and your new Ubuntu will be up in no time and the Grub dual-boot restored. Make sure you're booting th Ubuntu live media in UEFI mode, of course. How it boots is how it installs.

Comment: Thanks again.  So I was able to reinstall Ubuntu successfully, over the existing partitions, and  preserving all my old files and settings (in /home).  As per @CelticWarrior's suggestion, I selected all 3 Linux partitions (leaving out the NTFS /share) and made sure the format checkboxes were unticked.  This time the "Install Now" proceeded to completion.

It's still a mystery to me why this did not work previously, when I had the format checkbox ticked for the root partition, but with formatting off, the install proceeds fine. However, I am happy it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @CelticWarrior's suggestion, I was able to proceed beyond the "Install Now" and complete re-installation of Ubuntu on my dual-boot laptop, once I selected all Linux partitions (bar the NTFS /share) without formatting.

However, I don't have an answer to why it succeeds when formatting is not selected but fails otherwise.